# Building table about LULC historical (rows: categories; column: data by year)

Tags: qgis, shapefile, table

I'm working with datas of Land Use and Land Cover (LULC) (annual shapefiles) in a period of 1985 to 2018. I want to build a historical LULC table (rows = category; column = year LULC) using these shapefiles. I need to build this table for many watersheds. Nowadays, I'm building this table manually.

Are there any tools to build a table by shapefile attributes in QGIS?

Comment: What is LULC? s it Land Use and Land Cover? What have you tried by so far?

Comment: Hi Taras! Yes, LULC is Land Use and Land Cover. I exported attribute datatable of each shapefile (there are shapefile about 33 years - 1985-2018) and edited tables manually. However, I need to repeat this process many times.

Comment: So, you want to export attribute tables for all of your shapefiles programmatically? Which format the export has to inherit? Do you have some experience with PyQGIS?

Comment: Yes. I want export and join attributes tables by categories of LULC in a automatic manner. I didn't find a tool to do this. I don't have experience with PyQGiS, but I would be greatfull for receive sugestion of how to start (for resolve this and futures problems). The original datas are raster format. I want construct a historical about LULC area in a table. If there are simpler way to do this by raster, I accept suggestion too.